# Windows curl command corrupts zip files on upload to SFTP server

Tags: windows, curl

Per our IT department, I have to use a curl command to upload files to our SFTP server.

I use a Jenkins pipeline to build our artifacts on Windows build nodes, which are `*.zip` files, and this is the `curl` command I use

```shell
C:\> curl -V
curl 7.03.1 (Windows) libcurl/7.03.1 Schannel

C:\> curl -T ./build_artifact.zip -u 'user:password'  ftp://ftp.company.com/devops/test/build_artifact.zip --ftp-ssl-reqd --ftp-create-dirs -k
```

The file uploads correctly.

But when I download the file on my Mac and I unzip it, I get

```
$ unzip build_artifact.zip
Archive:  build_artifact.zip
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of build_artifact.zip or
        build_artifact.zip.zip, and cannot find build_artifact.zip.ZIP, period.
```

Note if I execute the same `curl` command on my Mac to upload to the SFTP site, I can readily unzip the artifact when I subsequently download it.

Any clues on why this happens, and how to fix it?

Comment: Is there any chance the source path would differ on the build server? `./build_artifact.zip` for example, might the command be running from a different start folder, which means the relative path doesn't point to a file?

One quick check for this would be to look at the size of the file. If it's 0 bytes, you might be uploading "file not found", if that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks. It's the same file. I did check the file size and it's the same. On my scripts, I do a `dir(env.WORKSPACE) {}` before I execute the `curl` command, and the `WORKSPACE` is where the `build_artifact.zip` file is.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Updating to the latest Git bash, which included `curl v8.x` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

This could be the common known issue based on the upload transfer of binary files using the `curl` command on Windows.

By default, `curl` on a Windows device uses ASCII transfer mode which can cause issues with binary files like `.zip` archives. Whereas on a Mac device, the `curl` command uses binary transfer mode as default.

To avoid this, override the ASCII transfer method by implicitly specifying the  transfer mode as binary, by using the `--ftp-binary` option.

See amended command below:

```
$ curl -T ./build_artifact.zip -u 'user:password' ftp://ftp.company.com/devops/test/build_artifact.zip --ftp-ssl-reqd --ftp-create-dirs -k --ftp-binary
```

Comment: I was hoping this would work. But I get `curl: option --ftp-binary is unknown`. Maybe later versions of `curl` have it, but apparently not `curl v7.x`.